# pipe "closing" after fclose()

Tags: c, unix

```
int fd[2];
void write_to_pipe(char* str)
{
    int file = fd[1];
    FILE *stream;
    //printf("writing to pipe : %s\n", str);
    stream = fdopen(file, "w");
    //printf("fdopen returned : %d\n",(int)stream);
    fprintf(stream, "%s", str);
    fclose(stream);
}



At main() : pipe(fd);
```

If I call `write_to_pipe` first then it works perfectly fine.

If the function is called second time then `fdopen` fails(returns 0).

I assumed the stream/pipe/somthing is closed

What is the safe way to "not close the pipe" and call the function multiple times

Compiler : gcc 6.3.1

---

p.s.
This read function could have similar problem too.

```
char* read_from_pipe()
{
    int file = fd[0];
    static char buf[100];
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen(file, "r");
    read(file,buf,100);
    fclose(stream);
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Your `read_from_pipe()` has a lot bigger problem than closing the file descriptor.  You're calling `read()` in a `FILE *`.  That won't work at all.  `read()` takes a file descriptor directly, and it will not NUL-terminate whatever it reads.

Comment: You should just use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) with `pclose`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But `popen()` doesn't provide a bi-directional pipe.  It's either read-only or write-only.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the snippet doesn't show any bi-directional communication, so `popen()` might indeed be enough. No gain for portability though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the safe way to "not close the pipe" and call the function multiple times

Don't use `fdopen()` on the file descriptor:

```
void write_to_pipe(char* str)
{
    write( fd[ 1 ], str, strlen( str ) );
}
```

or use `fdopen()` at the same scope as the pipe itself:

```
int fd[2];
 .
 .
 .
FILE *stream = fdopen( fd[ 1 ] );
 .
 .
 .
void write_to_pipe(char* str)
{
    fprintf(stream, "%s", str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard C doesn't know POSIX file descriptors, only `FILE *` is standard, and `fclose()` closes the file. This of course implies to do whatever is necessary on the platform to close the file, so in this case, calling `close()` on the underlying descriptor.

What you should do is just use `FILE *` wherever appropriate. So if you need a pipe as a backend for your `FILE *`, `fdopen()` the file right after creating the pipe. This way, you have your platform-specific code in a single place.

If you happen to need the file descriptor for anything else than closing the pipe, you can use `fileno()` on the `FILE *`, but then you have another platform-dependent part in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could `dup` the file descriptor and perform the `fdopen` on the duplicate.

```
int write_to_pipe(char* str)
{
    int file = dup(fd[1]);
    if(0>file)
       return -1;
    FILE *stream;
    //...
}
```

In any case, your function should probably return an integer so that it could signal possible errors that might occur inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the stdout file descriptor, which closes the pipe. Open it once and keep it around until you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

this function:

```
char* read_from_pipe()
{
    int file = fd[0];
    static char buf[100];
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen(file, "r");
    read(file,buf,100);
    fclose(stream);
    return buf;
}
```

contains several problems.

Suggest writing it similar to:

```
#define MAX_BUF_LEN 100

char* read_from_pipe()
{
     static char buf[ MAX_BUF_LEN +1 ];
     ssize_t byteCount = read( fd[0], buf, MAX_BUF_LEN );
     if( 0 > byteCount )
     { // an error occurred
         perror( "read from pipe failed" );
         buf[0] = '\0';
     }

     else if( 0 == byteCount )
     {
         fprintf( stderr, "no bytes read\n" );
         buf[0] = '\0';
     }

     else
     {
         buf[byteCount] = '\0';
     }

     return buf; 
} // end function: read_from_pipe
```

Note: `read()` does not terminate the char array, so the code has to do that And the array has to be 1 char longer than the max number of characters ask for in the `read()` statement.

Note: the syntax for `read()` wants a `int`, not `FILE*` for its' first parameter.  Here is the proper syntax:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

this function:

```
int fd[2];
void write_to_pipe(char* str)
{
    int file = fd[1];
    FILE *stream;
    //printf("writing to pipe : %s\n", str);
    stream = fdopen(file, "w");
    //printf("fdopen returned : %d\n",(int)stream);
    fprintf(stream, "%s", str);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

leaves a lot to be desired.

Suggest something similar to:

```
int fd[2];  << in file scope, so visible from functions

void write_to_pipe(char* str)
{
    //printf("writing to pipe : %s\n", str);
    ssize_t bytesWritten = write( fd[1], str, strlen(str) );

    if( strlen(str) != bytesWritten )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "write to pipe failed to write all bytes\n" );
    }

    else if( 0 > bytesWritten )
    {
        perror( "write to pipe failed" );
    }
} // end function: write_to_pipe
```

Answer (score -1):

[Duplicate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) the descriptor and use the duplicate in the `fdopen` call.